# How to add child elements in Soap Request XML using Java SAAJ

Tags: java, soap, groovy, soapui, saaj

I want to add the child element(Identifier) in the body of the Soap Request as below:

Expected Soap Request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:ns="nsurl">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <ns:GetRequest>
     <ns:Identifier Type="x" Value="y"/>      
  </ns:GetRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

With my code I am able to add the child element(Identifier) as below:

Actual Soap Request

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 xmlns:ns="nsurl">
 <soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
  <ns:GetRequest>
     <ns:Identifier>Type="x" Value="y"</ns:Identifier>      
  </ns:GetRequest>
 </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

And here is the java code:

```
    private static void createSoapEnvelope(SOAPMessage soapMessage) throws SOAPException {
    SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

    String myNamespace = "ns";
    String myNamespaceURI = "nsurl";

    // SOAP Envelope
    SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
    envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration(myNamespace, myNamespaceURI);


    // SOAP Body
    SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();

    SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("GetRequest", myNamespace);

    SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 =soapBodyElem.addChildElement("Identifier", myNamespace);
    soapBodyElem1.addTextNode("Type=\"x\" Value=\"y\"");


}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are using `SoapUI` tool.

You could use `Groovy Script` test step with below script to change the same.

```
def xmlString = """ <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="nsurl">  <soapenv:Header/>  <soapenv:Body>   <ns:GetRequest>      <ns:Identifier>Type="x" Value="y"</ns:Identifier>         </ns:GetRequest>  </soapenv:Body>  </soapenv:Envelope>"""
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlString)
//Get the Identifier node
def identifier = xml.'**'.find{it.name() == 'Identifier'}

//Create a map based on Identifier node value
def map = identifier.text().split(' ').collectEntries{ [(it.split('=')[0]) : it.split('=')[1].replace('"','')]}

//Remove the text value for Identifier node
identifier.replaceBody { '' }

//Set the attributes from the map
map.each{k,v -> identifier.@"$k" = v}
def newXml = groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
log.info newXml
```

You can quickly try it online <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/KwfFN2)</kbd>

Comment: This answer is possibly off topic. I guess the OP tagged the question with "soapui" simply because the expected request was produced with SoapUI.

Answer (score 0):

In the expected request, `Type` and `Value` are attributes, not part of the content of the `ns:Identifier` element. Therefore you need to use SAAJ's `addAttribute` (or DOM's `setAttributeNS`) method to add them.